# Is there any good solution for Facebook login with EE4 / EE5 in 2018? [YES !]

Tags: members, login, facebook, social

It's all in the title. Threads about logging users in EE with a facebook account seem to date from the last decade or so.

Is there any good solution for Facebook login with EE4 / EE5 in 2018 ?

**[ YES! ] 2019 UPDATE**

We used [Social Sign In from reinos.nl](https://addons.reinos.nl/social-sign-in) and it's worth every penny. Bonus points for the developer who implemented several feature requests very quickly (MSM support and multiple return URLs).

Answer (score 1):

I have not used it but I did stumble across "Smart Members PRO" on devotee https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/smart-members-pro

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Accepting your answer might make Smart Members PRO the de-facto solution, due to the lack of alternative. I think I should give it a try first ;)

Comment: Smart Members PRO works very well with Facebook login and many others.

Comment: Smart Members pro is a mess, it does way too many things to do anything well